# How to find number of days in the current year in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this problem I want to calculate number days of the current year.
somewhat like this

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR('2016-12-31');
Ans:366
```

but without mentioning the date
I tried this but it is giving me current day of the year

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE());
```

Please help

Comment: If the year is divisible by four but not divisible by 100 (unless also divisible by 400) then it is a leap year. You don't need MySQL for this.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure there are other ways but this is simple and works

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-12-31')) as days_in_year;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work too:

```
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(
    LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12-MONTH(NOW()) MONTH))
) AS NumberOfDaysInCurrentYear;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
select datediff(date(concat(year(curdate()) + 1, '-01-01')),
                date(concat(year(curdate()), '-01-01'))
               )
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/84508) is an example of it working.

Comment: Most unlike you, but that does not work! `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'date_format'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly . . . Clearly, I confused myself in writing the query.  It doesn't need both `date()` and `date_format()`, because the date is in the right format.

Comment: Hope you dont mind, not trying to be a smart-ass, pasted your fiddle over your answer to correct a bracketing hiccup

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT('2018-09-14', '%Y-12-31')); -- 365 days
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT('2019-09-14', '%Y-12-31')); -- 365 days
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT('2020-09-14', '%Y-12-31')); -- 366 days!!!
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT('2021-09-14', '%Y-12-31')); -- 365 days
SELECT DAYOFYEAR(DATE_FORMAT('2022-09-14', '%Y-12-31')); -- 365 days
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution to find the number of days in a given year you specify using any date within that year. Calculating the date difference between a year's first day, to the next year's first day.

```
DATEDIFF(MAKEDATE(YEAR(:date) + 1, 1), MAKEDATE(YEAR(:date), 1))
```